# How to efficiently extract data from JSON dictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I have recently used the following code to extract the ID of a location from a Foursquare API call with:

```
NSDictionary* foursquareJson = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:secureData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
NSDictionary *venuesDict = foursquareJson[@"response"];
NSArray *venuesArray = venuesDict[@"venues"];
NSDictionary *venuesDict2 = venuesArray[0];
NSArray *categoriesDict = venuesDict2[@"categories"];
NSDictionary *idDict = categoriesDict[0];
NSLog(@"ID is %@",idDict[@"id"]);
```

with original foursquareJson being:

```
2015-03-30 17:16:40.700 Voyagic[2833:718563] {
    meta =     {
        code = 200;
    };
    response =     {
        venues =         (
                        {
                categories =                 (
                                        {
                        icon =                         {
                            prefix = "https://ss3.4sqi.net/img/categories_v2/building/conventioncenter_";
                            suffix = ".png";
                        };
                        id = 4bf58dd8d48988d1ff931735;
                        name = "Convention Center";
                        pluralName = "Convention Centers";
                        primary = 1;
                        shortName = "Convention Center";
                    }
                );
                contact =                 {
                    formattedPhone = "+44 20 7222 5000";
                    phone = "+442072225000";
                };
                hereNow =                 {
                    count = 0;
                    groups =                     (
                    );
                    summary = "Nobody here";
                };
                id = 4b6599d4f964a520f8f52ae3;
                location =                 {
                    address = "Broad Sanctuary";
                    cc = GB;
                    city = London;
                    country = "United Kingdom";
                    distance = 2167;
                    formattedAddress =                     (
                        "Broad Sanctuary",
                        London,
                        "Greater London",
                        "SW1P 3EE",
                        "United Kingdom"
                    );
                    lat = "51.49997800145596";
                    lng = "-0.1289014132864838";
                    postalCode = "SW1P 3EE";
                    state = "Greater London";
                };
                name = "Queen Elizabeth II Conference Centre";
                referralId = "v-1427732200";
                specials =                 {
                    count = 0;
                    items =                     (
                    );
                };
                stats =                 {
                    checkinsCount = 3657;
                    tipCount = 15;
                    usersCount = 2407;
                };
                verified = 0;
            }
        );
    };
}
```

but there surely must be a better way of accessing the ID which I don't know about (instead of creating 4 dictionaries and 2 array, which seems somewhat excessive :/ ). Any help would be greatly appreciated  :)

Comment: Unless it's slowing down your app in a user-perceptible way, I wouldn't worry about it. While in theory you could write a JSON parser that only instantiates the objects when you need them, in reality it's probably not worth the trouble unless the JSON is very large. I've considered writing a stream JSON parser that parses the data as it downloads, so by the time the last packet arrives most of the JSON has been parsed, but it would only be useful for large responses.

Comment: Define 'better'. There are different ways, but you'll basically always be creating and referencing the container objects somewhere...

Comment: You can simplify the first couple parses as this: 

NSArray *venuesArray = [foursquareJson valueForKeyPath:@"response.venues"];

Comment: Normally one would parse the JSON once and then access the resulting "nest" of arrays and dictionaries multiple times to extract multiple pieces of data.  If the only data item you want is "id" you should see if there isn't a way to query your source for only that, since transmitting the unused data is likely more expensive than parsing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultimately, the data will need to be accessed through the lists of dictionaries and arrays somehow, it just depends on where you want that to happen. You could use or make a parser for the JSON but that will ultimately still need to map the JSON data similarly to what you are doing. A simple and shorter way of accessing the data would be to not  create a new variable in every iteration. Although it really is not much different:

```
NSDictionary *foursquareJson = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:secureData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
NSDictionary *objectId = foursquareJson[@"response"][@"venues"][0][@"categories"][0][@"id"];
NSLog(@"ID is %@",objectId);
```

Because of the dialogue in the comments of this answer I figured I should probably include a bit more information about your concern with creating "4 dictionaries and 2 arrays". When you use the JSON Serializer to create native objects from the JSON (first line above) you are creating all of the arrays and dictionaries needed to fully represent and store the entire JSON. The difference in code samples between what you originally posted and what I provided is really not a significantly different. If you are concerned with creating too many dictionaries or arrays you should attempt to filter out the JSON prior to deserializing it into native objects.

Comment: Note that you're not creating any fewer objects than the original.  Accessing an array or dictionary to extract an element does not "create" anything.

Comment: @Hot Licks I think that this is exactly what the PO doesn't understand right now. Maybe explaining that would be a nice addition to that answer.

Comment: I updated the answer to better address OP's concerns with memory. If you think it is still inadequate please let me know.